# SYS .write deja residuos en consola

Tags: python

```
sys.stdout.write('Starting')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
RL()
sys.stdout.write('Starting.')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
RL()
sys.stdout.write('Starting..')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
RL()
sys.stdout.write('Starting...')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
RL()
```

Cuando utilizo este codigo sucede que no borra bien el texto en consola, textos mas largos no se borran y dejan los residuos, si luego quiero poner un texto mas corto quedara en pantalla el texto mas largo.

Dejo aqui un ejemplo de un numero y el starting

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Conocen alguna alternativa/Solucion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar el retorno de carro '\r' como en las maquinas de escribir, que vuelve al principio de la linea por ejemplo:

```
import sys
import time
sys.stdout.write('\rStarting')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write('\rStarting.')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write('\rStarting..')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write('\rStarting...')
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
sys.stdout.write('\r            \r')
```

y si no funciona siempre puedes hacer un cls de la consola:

```
from os import system
system("cls")
```

Comment: No sirvió, a mi me sigue dejando residuos y aun me pregunto por que

Comment: Pues a mi no, pero será por tu función RL() que saca algo por consola

Comment: RL Solo tiene para Borrar la linea con /r, esa funcion no borra bien

Comment: Creo que esto no funcionaba en consolas antiguas o en algún tipo de emulación

Comment: /r no borra, solo vuelve al principio de la linea pero deja el residuo como dices tu. Esto borra sys.stdout.write('\r            \r')

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa es simplemente ir agregando puntos, en lugar de volver al principio y escribir todo de nuevo. Funciona en todos los ambientes Python.

Para imprimir se usa `print`. También puedes usar un `for` para no tener que repetir tantas veces el mismo código.

```
print('Starting', end='')
for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    RL()
    print('.', end='')
print()
```

El parámetro `end=cadena`) indica a `print()` lo que debe imprimir a continuación. Si no pones nada, agrega un `\n`. En este caso no quiero el cambio de línea, asi que le digo que imprima *nada*.

#### Demo

```
import time

def RL():
    pass

print('Starting', end='')

for i in range(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    RL()
    print('.', end='')
print()
```

produce:

```
Starting...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Bonito, pero no es lo que se pide.